# How can I return a NumPy array using FastAPI?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, opencv, fastapi

I have a TensorFlow [Keras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keras) [deep learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_learning) model in the form of an h5 file.

How can I upload an image and return a NumPy array in FastAPI?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import tensorflow as tf

model=load_model("complete_model.h5")
app = FastAPI()

def prepare(image):
    IMG_SIZE = 224
    new_array = cv2.resize(image, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
    return new_array.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,3)

@app.post("/")
async def root(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    global model
    content = await file.read()
    nparr = np.fromstring(content, np.uint8)
    img = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR).astype(np.float32)
    prediction = model.predict(prepare(img))
    return prediction
```

When uploading the image using Swagger UI, I get the following error:

```
line 137, in jsonable_encoder
data = dict(obj)
TypeError: 'numpy.float32' object is not iterable
```

Working code without FastAPI:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2

model=load_model("complete_model.h5")

def prepare(image):
    IMG_SIZE = 224
    new_array = cv2.resize(image, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
    return new_array.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,3)

img = cv2.imread("./test.jpeg").astype(np.float32)
prediction = model.predict(prepare(img))
print(prediction)
```

Result in the terminal:

```
[[0.25442022 0.74557984]]
```

How can I get the same result while using FastAPI?

Comment: It doesn't, just shows this ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\ranveer\anaconda3\envs\tfjs\lib\site-packages\fastapi\encoders.py", line 137, in jsonable_encoder
    data = dict(obj)
TypeError: 'numpy.float32' object is not iterable

During the handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\ranveer\anaconda3\envs\tfjs\lib\site-packages\fastapi\encoders.py", line 141, in jsonable_encoder
    data = vars(obj)
TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is thrown when returning the `response` (i.e., `prediction` in your case) from your endpoint. It looks like FastAPI is trying to convert the NumPy array into a `dict`, using the [`jsonable_encoder`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/encoder/), which is [used internally by FastAPI when returning a value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73974946/17865804) from an endpoint, and which seems to call Python's [`vars()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) method, as shown in the error you provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71102658/fastapi-uploaded-image-as-np-float32-to-a-deep-learning-model-opencv#comment125690003_71102658) (have a look at the discussion [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/2133), as well as the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-directly/)). Thus, what you could do is to convert the NumPy array into a Python `list` and then serialise it into a `JSON` object:

```
return json.dumps(prediction.tolist())
```

On OpenAPI (Swagger UI), you will still be able to see the expected result. However, if you need to convert it back to a NumPy array, you can parse the JSON string as shown below.

```
arr = np.asarray(json.loads(resp.json()))  # resp.json() if using Python requests
```

If you would like to return the NumPy array as raw bytes and display the image in the browser or download it, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71639658/17865804).