# How can I return a NumPy array in FastAPI?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, fastapi, vision

```
@app.post("/predict/")
async def predict(file:UploadFile = File(...)):
    bytes_str = io.BytesIO(await file.read())
    img = Image.open(bytes_str)
    img_array = np.array(img.convert('RGB'))
    img_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (1024,1024))
    img_final = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis = 0)
    pred = model.predict(img_final)
```

This code returns a NumPy array and I need to return it on FastAPI on an endpoint, but what could be the strategy?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I return a NumPy array using FastAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71102658/how-can-i-return-a-numpy-array-using-fastapi)

Answer (score 0):

Try a simple pred.tolist() to return a normal list that fastapi understands.