# FastAPI: Internal Server Error when returning ML model prediction

Tags: python, pipeline, fastapi

I would like to test my pipeline in FastAPI, but I can't find the mistake in my code. When I test it using the Visual Studio Code (using a `print()` statement), it works. However, when I try accessing the endpoint through the browser, I get `Internal Server Error`. It works when I return something else as the prediction results (e.g., some string), instead of the actual prediction results.

Here is my code:

```
class FraudDetection333(BaseModel):
    """
    Input features validation for the ML model
    """
    user_id: int
    signup_day: int
    signup_month: int
    signup_year: int
    purchase_day: int
    purchase_month: int
    purchase_year: int
    purchase_value: float
    source: str
    browser: str
    sex: str
    age: int

@api.post("/predictions_test",tags=['DecisionTreeClassifier'])
def predictions_test(fraud:FraudDetection333):
    """
    :param:input data from the post request
    :return predicted type
    """
    features = [[
    fraud.user_id,
    fraud.signup_day,
    fraud.signup_month,
    fraud.signup_year,
    fraud.purchase_day,
    fraud.purchase_month,
    fraud.purchase_year,
    fraud.purchase_value,
    fraud.source,
    fraud.browser,
    fraud.sex,
    fraud.age
    ]]
    rf_model = joblib.load('./rf_model.pkl')
    new = (pd.DataFrame(features, index = ['0'], columns = ['user_id','signup_day',         
'signup_month', 'signup_year', 
        'purchase_day', 'purchase_month', 'purchase_year','purchase_value',
        'source','browser','sex','age']))
    new_prediction = rf_model.predict(new)
    return {
        "Predicted transaction(1 - fraud, 0 - not fraud)": new_prediction
    }
```

If I try the below (using a `print()` statement), it prints out the expected outcome:

```
featuress={
  "user_id": 22058,
  "signup_day": 24,
  "signup_month": 2,
  "signup_year": 2015,
  "purchase_day": 18,
  "purchase_month": 4,
  "purchase_year": 2015,
  "purchase_value": 34,
  "source": "SEO",
  "browser": "Chrome",
  "sex": "M",
  "age": 39
}
rf_model = joblib.load('./rf_model.pkl')
new = (pd.DataFrame(featuress, index = ['0'], columns = ['user_id','signup_day',     
 'signup_month', 'signup_year', 
        'purchase_day', 'purchase_month', 'purchase_year','purchase_value',
        'source','browser','sex','age']))
new_prediction = rf_model.predict(new)
print(new)
print(new_prediction)
```

If I type `return {"Predicted transaction(1 - fraud, 0 - not fraud)": 'Hi'}`, it also works.
Image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxUKv.png).

Comment: How are you testing the API on the server, and what is the error message on the server?

Comment: The server log should have the complete error message - i.e. exactly what caused the server to respond with internal server error.

Comment: Since you're not sending data into to your dataframe with identical structure between the working and borked code it seems like it can be caused other issues as well.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: it sends response as `JSON` but `JSON` can send only basis data  types - `string`, `int`, `float`, `list`, `dict`. It can't send `DataFrame` nor `numpy.array`. You have to convert it to basis data types.

Answer (score 2):

The `model.predict()` function returns a [`numpy.ndarray`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.ndarray.html) (you could verify that using `print(type(new_prediction))`). You can't just return it in that format; hence, the `Internal Server Error`.

**Option 1** is to simply retireve and return the first element of that numpy array:

```py
return {'prediction': new_prediction[0]}
```

**Option 2** is to convert the numpy array into a Python list using the [`.tolist()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) method.

```py
return {'prediction': new_prediction.tolist()}
```

Related answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71849860/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71104203/17865804).