# fastapi post request : getting null instead of numpy array

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn

I am trying to run this code from a directory, `C:\users\user1\plant_app\main.py`
Edit: I am able to start the server, but I can't get the numpy array.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
import uvicorn
from io import BytesIO
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image


def read_image(data):
    return np.array(Image.open(BytesIO(data)))

app=FastAPI()
@app.get('/check')
async def check():
     return {'message':'hello world'}
@app.post('/predict')
async def predict(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
     image=read_image(await file.read())
     return image


if __name__=='__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app,host='localhost',port=8000)
```

I am getting this error.

```
PS C:\Users\user1\plant_app> python -u "c:\Users\user1\plant_app\main.py"
INFO:     Started server process [21740]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://localhost:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     127.0.0.1:58115 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It looks like your code only defines urls for `/check` and `/predict`.  There is no `/` url.

Comment: You might also find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73240097/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73264904/17865804) helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
@app.get('/')
dуf root():
    return {'message':'FastAPI app'}
```

you should define `/` url

Comment: That seems to start the server, but when I upload an image using docs I am getting `null` and `{"detail":"Not Found"}` with postman @Baktybek Baiserkeev

Answer (score 0):

```
@app.get('/')
async def root():
    return {'message': 'test'}
```

Try adding this because it seems like the GET route to '/' hasn't been declared.

Comment: That seems to start the server, but when I upload an image using docs I am getting `null` and `{"detail":"Not Found"}` with postman @Kionling

Answer (score 0):

We can access the API from http://localhost:8000/check or http://localhost:8000/predict. Or we can also use SwaggerUI which is integrated with FastAPI to interact with API.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I think the problem is returning the image. You need to create a response with a type of image (here image/png as my test case was a png file). I wasn't sure of what output you wanted. So, I made three services: one returns the np array, the other returns the shape of the array, and finally the one returns the image itself. Check the following links for more info:

- get bytes from upload: [How to upload File in FastAPI, then to Amazon S3 and finally process it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70520522/how-to-upload-file-in-fastapi-then-to-amazon-s3-and-finally-process-it)
- return np array in a service: [How can I return a NumPy array using FastAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71102658/how-can-i-return-a-numpy-array-using-fastapi)
- return an image in a service: [How do I return an image in fastAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55873174/how-do-i-return-an-image-in-fastapi)

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
import uvicorn
from io import BytesIO
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from fastapi.responses import Response
import json

def read_image(data):
    return np.array(Image.open(BytesIO(data)))

app=FastAPI()

@app.get('/')
async def check():
     return {'message':'hello world'}


@app.post('/array')
async def predict_array(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
     content = await file.read()
     image = read_image(content)
     return json.dumps(image.tolist())


@app.post('/shape')
async def predict_shape(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
     content = await file.read()
     image = read_image(content)
     return {'shape': image.shape}

@app.post('/image')
async def return_image(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
     content = await file.read()
     return Response(content=content, media_type="image/png")

if __name__=='__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app,host='localhost', port=8000)
```